# koa2 post always show Method Not Allowed？

Tags: koa

```
//server.js
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa();
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
app.use(bodyParser());   
const Router = require('koa-router');
const fs = require('fs');

const router = new Router();
const UserController = require('./server/controller/user.js');
const checkToken = require('./server/token/checkToken.js');
router.get('/user/login', async ctx => {
 ctx.body = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync( './pass.json'));
 console.log(ctx.body);
 });

router.post('/signin', async (ctx, next) => {
  var
    name = ctx.request.body.name || '',
    password = ctx.request.body.password || '';
    console.log(`signin with name: ${name}, password: ${password}`);
  if (name === 'koa' && password === '12345') {
 ctx.response.body = `<h1>Welcome, ${name}!</h1>`;
  } else {
 ctx.response.body = `<h1>Login failed!</h1>
 <p><a href="/">Try again</a></p>`;
 }
 });

     app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(8090, () => {
   console.log('The server is running at http://localhost:' + 8090);
 });
```

---

```
koa:2.52
koa-bodyparse:4.21
koa-router:7.4
```

when I type http://localhost:8090/user/login can get the Json data,but type http://localhost:8090/signin always show 405  Methods Not Allowed ,(debian firefxo) show Request Method "GET",response Allow: POST,Connection: "keep-alive" 
I hope get your help.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem, POSTing to http://localhost:8090/signin works fine. Could it be that you are sending GET instead of POST? Or that you are sending POST to the wrong route?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you shouldn't use the chrome to do the post cause when you type some url, the default method is GET not POST， you can check it out from the NETwork。 Try postman it will work.Sorry for my bad english,I hope it will help XD

Comment: I use postman ,the problem exsits still.

Comment: Could u show some key code ?